# Alter/insert into the links variable in a field_collection

Tags: navigation, entities

I am currently working with the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module, but I have stumbled into a small problem.

I am trying to alter the links variable (currently there is Edit & Delete links) on a field_collection, as I want to add a link to it. I believe I have tried everything, such as `hook_entity_view_alter()`, or a preprocess function, but nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to solve this, without hacking core?

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Try posting your code as part of your question.

Comment: I have simply tried to find content->links but it's no where to be found. Doubt the code will help that much, its just a bunch of dpm, in a bunch of hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a custom module you can use hook_field_attach_view_alter(). In this example I'm using the distribution profile eRecruiter so there is a bundle called resume with several field collections and in an entity type profile2. Every time there is a field attached to a field collection this hook is fired recursively but the links are not contained there.

```
/**
* Implements hook_field_attach_view_alter()
* 
* @param mixed $output
* @param mixed $context
*/
function helper_field_attach_view_alter(&$output, $context) {
  if ($output['#entity_type'] == 'profile2' && $output['#bundle'] == 'resume') {
    $f = 'do stuff here';
  }
}
```

So you understand how the links work here is some of the code used in field_collection.module.

The links are created in a render array. Don't worry about 'links__field_collection_view' too much because it doesn't do anything. When the #theme function is called more familiarly as theme('link__field_collection_view', $variables) it looks first for TEMPLATE_link__field_collection_view(&$variables) or link--field-collection-view.tpl.php however if it doesn't find it, it will use as it does in this case theme_links();

```
  $links = array(
    '#theme' => 'links__field_collection_view',
  );
  $links['#attributes']['class'][] = 'field-collection-view-links';
  foreach (array('edit', 'delete') as $op) {
    if ($settings[$op] && field_collection_item_access($op == 'edit' ? 'update' : $op, $field_collection)) {
      $links['#links'][$op] = array(
        'title' => $settings[$op],
        'href' => $field_collection->path() . '/' . $op,
        'query' => drupal_get_destination(),
      );
    }
  }
```

hook_admin_paths() is used to make the links rendered in the dialog window.

```
function field_collection_admin_paths() {
  if (variable_get('node_admin_theme')) {
    return array(
      'field-collection/*/*/edit' => TRUE,
      'field-collection/*/*/delete' => TRUE,
      'field-collection/*/add/*/*' => TRUE,
    );
  }
}
```

hook_menu() is set up for the link callback in this case the edit link

```
  $items[$path . '/%field_collection_item/edit'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('field_collection_item_form', $count),
    'access callback' => 'field_collection_item_access',
    'access arguments' => array('update', $count),
    'title' => 'Edit',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
    'file' => 'field_collection.pages.inc',
  );
```

Comment: I found you answer very explaining, but i'm still don't understand how to solve this? Should i be able to add links with <module>_field_attach_view_alter ? I guess i can't call the field_collection_field_formatter_links.

Comment: What is the entity you are attaching the field collections to? And what is the bundle? There is an entity called 'node' and bundles called 'page'. If there is a field collection attached to the node type article, then `if ($output['#entity_type'] == 'node' && $output['#bundle'] == 'page')` would test for the content to give you access to the links. Perhaps, hook_page_alter would give you access too but the links might be deeply hidden. What link to you want to add?